# Cloudera Manager Metric - Login Failure metric

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to create a dashboard in Cloudera Manager using Chart Builder. I want to show metrics related to Login Failure rate (login_failure_rate). However, it doesn't reflect the actual status. Is there any other metric related to this. kindly assist me regarding this issue.